# How can I make a window "read only" in GNU Screen?

Tags: gnu-screen

I started a really long process and would like to check it occasionally how it goes, but want to avoid interrupt it by mistake. Is there a way to set only this window "read only" ?

Comment: Not that I know of. You can always just minimize it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `chacl` command may be useful here: you need to remove write permission for all users at a window number N (0 in the example below):

```
<Ctrl-A>:chacl * -w 0<Enter>
```

where `*` means "for all connected users", `-w` for "remove write permission", 0 is the number of window being locked.
To restore write permissions:

```
<Ctrl-A>:chacl * +w 0<Enter>
```